# What is the best way of storing a geographical information in a relation db?

Tags: database, relational-database

I want to save a geographical data in a relational db and be able to query for data based on their location (country, state or similar not coordinates).

My current solution is to have 4 extra fields (all countries I'm interested in have 2 or 3 administrative divisions) in my table and filter on strings. But I realize that this is a bad solution and would like to normalize my table.

I will also use that data to determine which page my users wants to visit, so it must be simple to lookup a request like "/usa/california/san_fransisco/..."

The only other solution I can come up with is to store those 4 extra fields in another table and link them with a foreign key but that would still mean some data duplication as country name would duplicated in allot of rows.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you also interested in storing data such as GPS coordinates, borders, geometric data? That might lead to a GIS solution, but it sounds like you do not need that...

Comment: No besides the geographical data I will save text in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizing is definitely the way to go. Databases are designed to function that way. Yes the query might look long but it's not that bad. It might look something like this:

```
select * --or whatever fields you need
  from Customer
       left outer join City    on (Customers.CityID = City.CityID)
       left outer join State   on (City.StateID     = State.StateID)
       left outer join Country on (State.CountryID  = Country.CountryID)
 where CustomerID = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with putting the info in tables. Their called lookup tables. If you want to go the full relational route, you can have the entity link with a foreign key to the city lookup table. The city table links to the state table. The state table links to the country table. You could also store a text version of the complete location in the entity's original table for data display.

Comment: I like the idea of having relations between city - state - country in the way you describe but it seems like allot of work to lookup a request. Wouldn't I need to make a query with 3 joins for each web request?

Comment: Like Fake below me says, that's not an expensive join. Looking up based on strings is actually MUCH slower than the join.

Answer (score 0):

> My current solution is to have 4 extra fields (all countries I'm interested in have 2 or 3 administrative divisions) in my table and filter on strings. But I realize that this is a bad solution and would like to normalize my table.

I don't think that this is a bad solution. Storing simple geographical/address-based information per row and using WHERE to fetch all records that match is fairly standard procedure. Using a foreign key to link to a separate table is going to be additional work and won't be any faster.

The searching/request using a RESTful interface (as you suggested) is a good idea, however.

Comment: Yes perhaps I shouldn't worry to much about normalization and keep it simple. But I'm still afraid of blocking my self in the future; if I decide to add support for translation into other languages or similar.

Comment: Queries using UPDATE WHERE handles those types of cases rather well. As to your other comment below:

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize the Enter key submitted rather than put a line break in. Anyway, your comment "Wouldn't I need to make a query with 3 joins for each web request?" is correct when using multiple tables like this. Just because you can think relationally and might feel "powerful" as a result doesn't make it the best solution. Use DESCRIBE SELECT to compare performance and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Go the normalized route. Joining tables is NOT slow, or complicated. PK of each table will be an integer with a clustered index. Foreign keys will have an index.  The join is going to fly.

If you want to list cities in a drop down list, you don't want duplicates. You may list all the cities under a state. De-normalized will slow your query with "distinct", i guarantee you that is slower going the de-normalized route. ironic?

But there is a case for de-normalized. There are millions of addresses. It will probably not be feasible to enter all addresses in your application. So you are going to rely on..... free text input from the user. In this case you don't care about exact correctness or duplicates, you are forced to just accept whatever is data is thrown at you due to the impossibility of having exhaustive data to validate against. And you would rather not bother inserting to "lookup" tables as you don't trust the input to begin with.

You could go for a re-cursive model if you want ultra flexibility to handle different countries.  Some countries may not have states, counties, etc. They all have their own hierarchy.

Comment: I would love to have a normalized solution but I can't see any easy ways of doing a lookup from a web request. I'm really new to databases so I might be missing something but wouldn't I have to make something like this to query in a normalized solution: "SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN city ON data.path_key = city.key INNER JOIN state ON city.parent = state.key INNER JOIN country ON state.parent = country.key WHERE data.name = 'city_park' AND city.name = 'san_fransisco' AND state.name = 'california' AND country.name = 'usa'" (Sorry for the long query)

Comment: Don't name a table "data". The name should describe the data. 

Here is how I would model it. With clustered indexes on the PK columns, regular indexes on FK's.

Country
---------
idCountry int PK
CountryName varchar(60)
unique constraint on CountryName 

State
---------
idState int PK
idCountry int FK
StateName varchar(60)
unique constraint on combo idCountry/StateName

City
---------
idCity int PK
idState int FK
CityName varchar(60)
unique constraint on combo idState/CityName

PointOfInterest
---------
idPOI int PK
idCity int FK
POIName varchar(60)
unique constraint on combo idCity/POIName